# Visual studio not recognizing src attribute when trying to refer to the index.js file

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, src

I am writing my javascript code in the file "index.js". When I use the src attribute in the "index.html" file it is not working. I am using visual basic editor.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script> src="index.js" </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run live server I would like for it to execute the code in both files.

Comment: `src` is an attribute, not content.

Comment: `<script src="index.js"></script>` != `<script>src="index.js"</script>`.  The former is an attribute.  What you have is content.

Comment: try `<script src="index.js"> </script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `<script>` tag, you should use the src as an **attribute**, not Html Content.

So instead of doing:

```html
<script> src="index.js" </script>
```

You should do:

```html
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

To learn more about attributes, I highly suggest looking it up on sites such as w3schools.

Answer (score 1):

As SLasks mentioned in the comment, `src`is an attribute not a content meaning your `script`tag should like this:

```
<script src="index.js"> </script>
```